# what does self .write mean in thus code?

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

I have been working on developing an OpenERP module in Ubuntu 12.04.I have been looking over Internet as i am a newbie in this type of development. I wanted to know what does `self.write` mean in OpenERP development under Python language. I will be very glad if I can get some understanding words on the following line of code :

```
self.write(cr, uid, [id], {'image': tools.image_resize_image_big(value)}, context=context)
```

Please help , reply as soon as possible.
Regards
(arsalan)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 3):

self.write() Is the ORM(Object Relational Mapping) method defined in OpenERP.
In the structure of OpenERP, there will be class (objects) having dictionary _columns = {}. With the mechanism of ORM, a new table having the same name as class will be created in Database. Inside the _columns = {} dictionary, we give some fields. These fields are the columns of created tables. 
For Example, the code below

class hr_job(osv.osv):

```
   _columns = {
       'name': fields.char('Job Name', size=128, required=True, select=True),
        }
```

will create a table named hr_job into database and a field of this table 'name'. 
If you write 'self.write()' method in this class, it will write/modify the value for the particular field in the table hr_job. 
In you case, it will change the value for image field of the table(class) from which it belongs. Hope this will Help you.

Comment: Good . But I am little confused with the parameters that are in this function . like cr , uid , id. waht does they do here

Comment: All ORM methods have some parameters so that they can communicate with db. cr is the Database cursor object used to connect with db. uid is the id of user currently logged in. [id] or [ids] is list of id or ids on which we want to perform db operations.

Comment: but what about implementation of id , cr etc

Comment: hey , can u give make me understand a code with such parameters. I will be highly thankful

Answer (score 2):

`self` is a reference to the current instance. So `self.write` is a reference to the `write` method of the current instance's class. Presumably the class is a file-like object. Hard to say more without knowing what kind of class you're dealing with.